# Eclipse's 'syso' Shortcut is Not Working?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, ide, settings

I have been having this problem for a while and I have been constantly searching for an answer everywhere and finally chose to just ask it here. All the other posts I have seen don't fix my problem and I have tried doing the following:

- Changed the binding of the shortcut
- Made sure that is was checked under templates
- Made sure all my settings were correct
- Autocompletion on

When I type `syso` and press Ctrl + Space, instead of instantly giving me the insertion or shortcut I want, it just opens the 'Intelligent Proposals' menu and I have to press Ctrl + Space again in order to get to the 'Template Proposals' menu where I can actually double click "'syso' - print to standard out" and then it gives me the full `System.out.println`. It really does mess with flow and is very annoying.

Any fixes to my problem? Thanks,

- Sa'id

Comment: What you mean by  `Intelligent Proposals` menu and 'Intelligent Proposals' menu?. You can share screen shot here http://imgur.com. When you press Ctrl+Space it opens up `Content Assist` popup(or context)menu which includes Java types and Templates both. Check in Windows > Preferences > General > Keys` Whether it binds to one command or more. It should be only one.

Comment: It works for me with Eclipse Luna. I just installed Eclipse Mars (Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200) to my new laptop and there I get the menu. Any real shortcut available in Eclipse Mars?

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem and figured it out after playing around with some settings. So, here's what you should do:

1. Go to Windows->Preferences-Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced.
2. Check on the box saying- Java Proposals.
3. Uncheck the box saying- Java Proposals (Code Recommenders).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem in Eclipse with the 'Template Proposals' menu popping up instead of completing the sysout shortcut. In my case, a plug-in installed recently was to blame. I unchecked all the templates for the plug-in in Preferences/(plug-in)/Templates - and this did the trick for me. Now the selection menu doesn't pop up any more, and syso + CTRL-SPACE works again as it should.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13611039)

Comment: OK, sorry. I edited and rephrased my answer. But I humbly disagree with the review: I had exactly the same problem, I found a fix, so how come it does not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: In this instance, it is not clear that the root problem is the same for your situation as for the OP. Because of this, your solution may work, but it might not. Iterating the solution for the OP's problem should occur through comments.

Comment: I thought the idea was to ask a question, wait for suggestions, try them out, and let everyone know which one worked. The OP has been struggling with this problem for a long time, the root of the problem is unclear for anyone, he specifically asks for any suggestions, and when I present a possible solution, it is recommended for deletion, on the grounds that it might not work. And what if this IS the solution that will work for him? Wouldn't it be better to let him try it out? Following your line of reasoning, any answer with "Try..." makes no sense, as it might not work.

Comment: What is more, in his profile the OP says: "I program mainly in Python and Java." So it is very likely that he has the PyDev plug-in installed in Eclipse, thus the root problem is very likely to be the same as in my situation and he may find my solution useful.

Comment: Note the link to [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) in the initial comment.

Comment: I proved in my two previous comments that OP's problem may well have the same root as mine, and that my solution may well work for him, but I can see that I got another recommendation for deletion. So please, delete the post alltogether, and I am deleting my account, as the moderation here is the most unfriendly, discouraging and restrictive I have ever experienced. I really regret joining in, being part of it and trying to contribute.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his answer as currently provided.  This is a potentially viable solution that will answer some users questions for this problem.  It is disappointing to me the inertia of disdain that was maintained here. The OPs original post was just as reasonable, he seems to have been steered into a worse state, and returned it into a good state.   @Imo there is no possible way to prove that his situation is or is not the same situation as the question OP's; so I strongly disagree with your logic in applying that test as some sort of condition only to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Select any string then press Ctrl + Space eclipse detects the context.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already know how to do this. My problem is before this problem showed for whatever reason, I was able to JUST press Ctrl+Space and it would automatically insert a `System.out.println();` statement. I don't want to have to go through a menu to select exactly what I want, since Eclipse should already know what I want when I put Syso and press Ctrl + Space.

Comment: In my case when I type `syso` then Ctrl+space it automatically inserts `System.out.println`, But when I press `sys` then ctrl+space, I will get `syserr, sysout,systrace and System class` in the proposal window. edit your question and post some screen shots

Comment: Sorry, fixed and made more specific. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this out

1. Go to Windows->Preferences-Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
2. Select Template proposals and click Ok

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom with eclipse 2021-06.

I discovered that the template named "syso" was gone.

Recreating "syso" worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work because ctrl+space was being used by another program Ubuntu(I-Bus) in my case ref. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema) Try changing ctrl-space by another key combination in general->keys to find out if this is causing the problem and try sysout instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Windows-Preferences-Java-Editor-Templates**

1. Here you can check if you have "syso" already and if so just check the box.
2. If you do not have check box with "syso"-create new "New.." , type name: *syso*, give your description if you want to, and enter the Pattern: *System.out.println();* , press OK
3. Press "Apply" , then "OK"
4. Check if it works!

Also, if it still does not work for you, go to 
**Windows-Preferences-Java-Editor-Content Assist -Favorites**

Here, press "New Type" -enter: *System.out.println();* , press OK , press Apply.

I hope it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was capitalizing the S in Sysout. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you should use sysout then ctrl + space. in windows and command + space in mac.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows>Preferences>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced and select the checkboxes for 1.Java proposals, 2.SWT Template proposals and 3.Template proposals. Now your shortcut for syso and ctrl+space will work. This worked for me, I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score -1):

I have both Chinese and English language input. Ctr + space could also mean switch language input. So make sure you are under English input

Answer (score -1):

Only for those who are using **eclipse editor**;

Check you are using **syso -> ctrl+space** in a valid coding area. I mean, you can't have a SOP statement inside class, it can be inside a function only, i.e. either inside `main()` or any user defined methods.

Answer (score -2):

- Step 1: Type `sysout`
- Step 2: Click `Ctrl + space`
- Step 3: Double click on `sysout-print` to standard out option.